# How can I read messages from another device in EE2E

Tags: end-to-end-encryption

How can I read messages between me and other people if I connect to my account from another device(mobile, other web browser)
I don't have the private key in other device?
In my server I just store the public key of each user
also I store the private key in indexDB
I'm using kbpgp to encrypt messages and read them in chat app.

Comment: You don't.  That's the entire point-  without those private keys you can't read the messages.  If you could read the messages on another device, so could anyone else.  Its up to you to decide whether the extra security of end to end encryption is worth the loss of convenience of access on multiple devices.

Comment: @GabeSechan can you explain then how whatsapp web work(barebone), according to what they said(messages cannot be read by them). how can I login to whatsapp web and read the message sent from mobile?

Comment: Well, I did find this:  https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/119552/how-does-end-to-end-encryption-work-with-whatsapp-web   But basically sending a message from web to your own device would be easy-  just need that public key to be sent to the browser. Encrypt it with that then send it to your device.  If you can read messages on web sent from your device previously, then something questionable is going on.